# RavenDB 2.5 failed to run on IIS Express

Tags: ravendb, iis-express

I have recently upgrade RavenDB from 1.0 to 2.5 (build 2750) in Visual Studio 2012 and II Express 8.  IIS express web server starts fine. The RavenDB console cannot be loaded. I reboot the pc and start RavenBD again, it shows me "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable." Other web project runs ok on IIS Express. The config of AnonymousAccess is set to Admin.

It works well with RaveDB 1.0 in the same environment and same pc. Some My coworkers experienced the same issue, some did not have any problem to run it. What's possible wrong?

Comment: Bounty or not, this isn't a great question for StackOverflow because it is focusing on the operational aspect of RavenDB rather than any particular programming perspective.  Within the StackExchange network, the question fits best on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/), but since there is very little RavenDB coverage there, I highly suggest you bring your question to the [RavenDB Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb) instead.  You can ignore the crossposting warning, since this clearly belongs there.

Comment: @MattJohnson is correct about ServerFault being a better place. But for now, how large is your data set? Do you have enough memory, or does it keep getting recycled before RavenDB is finished starting? Anything in the Event Viewer? RavenDB can appear unresponsive until it is finished with large startup tasks relating to starting up the databases if they're new.